# jhipster monolith to microservice migration: no authorization information forwarded?

Tags: spring, keycloak, jhipster, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I started migrating my jhipster monolith into microservices: gateway / ui / backend for the beginning. but now I am already stuck - **the authentication information seems not to get forwarded to the microservice**. or let's say I do not know **which part of the system is responsible for?** a call to `services/api` therefore results in a HTTP 401 response by the backend.

the applications are pretty straight forward created via `jhipster`, no major changes yet. started the keycloak service via provided docker-compose.

so the UI loggs in via keycloak. receives a `JSESSIONID`? I did see that **the gateway made the OAuth2 token exchange at this point, so I assume he should append that on downstream calls?** calling `/services/api` the gateway receives:

```sh
Request received for GET '/services/api/projects?page=0&size=3&loadArchived=false&loadAll=false&sort=startTime,asc&sort=id':

HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /services/api/projects ]

servletPath:/services/api/projects
pathInfo:null
headers: 
sec-fetch-mode: cors
referer: http://localhost:9000/
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
cookie: io=u8lImSrLEEZI1wudAAAg; XSRF-TOKEN=0ee385f0-7035-455c-a62f-53e4fb920af3; JSESSIONID=-MJuDH_RKSEBKWa3fEudYqX1fQII_8FMdqec2gc1
host: localhost:9000
connection: close
dnt: 1
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
sec-fetch-dest: empty


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
  BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

whereas the microservice (`api`) does not have any sensitive information available. or I might not see it? I remember something about spring security hiding authentication headers.

```
Request received for GET '/api/projects?page=0&size=3&loadArchived=true&loadAll=true&sort=startTime,asc&sort=id':

HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /api/projects ]

servletPath:/api/projects
pathInfo:null
headers: 
sec-fetch-mode: cors
referer: http://localhost:9000/?showArchived=true&showAll=true
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
x-forwarded-proto: http
Connection: Keep-Alive
x-forwarded-port: 9000
Host: localhost:8081
dnt: 1
x-forwarded-for: 127.0.0.1
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
x-forwarded-host: localhost:9000
x-forwarded-prefix: /services
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
sec-fetch-dest: empty


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter
  BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

(maybe) important notice: I don't use Eureka. I "hardcoded" the route for now (`application-dev.yml` in `gateway`). does that change anything in the behavior?

```yaml
zuul:
  routes:
    api:
      path: /**
      url: http://localhost:8081/
```

the code is available for public if anyone wants to check something: https://github.com/bbortt/event-planner/tree/feature/split-into-oauth2-modules. let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Your git repo does not include the options you used to generate your apps (.yo-rc.json or JDL), no jhipster version either, so it's difficult to say what's wrong but for sure you gateway lacks few crucial classes like AuthorizationHeaderFilter, AccessControlFilter or SwaggerBasePathRewritingFilter. Your architecture without service discovery is surprising, not sure what is your objective.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks very much for your comment. it pointed me into the right direction. answered my own question and also yours on my project setup. see below. have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I think @GaëlMarziou pointed me into the right direction with his comment: Thanks very much!
So, I ha previously generated the Gateway using JHipster-Generator 6.x.x and update to 7.something (latest stable as of today). Regenerate the gateway and works like a charm now. He perfectly appends Authorization header information on downstream requests.

To briefly answer your questions:

> not include the options you used to generate your apps (.yo-rc.json or JDL)

Well, I think JHipster is a *great* way to get started - but not to keep maintaining your projekt. Therefore, I like using it to kickstart my projects, but then getting rid of it. But, I certainly agree that it would've helped in this case, to track down a JHipster related problem.

> Your architecture without service discovery is surprising, not sure what is your objective.

I think k8s can take perfectly care of discovery and load balancing on static routes as well. It is probably a matter of preferences, but I don't like keeping track of one more server if I don't necessarily need it ;)

Comment: I have same approach as you to use JHipster to kickstart projects but I always commit the .yo-rc.json or JDL files because 1 or 2 years later I (or my successors) may have difficulties to update some libraries/frameworks and in such case I re-generate with latest version of JHipster in an empty folder to see how JHipster team did solve this update. It does make sense only for projects you expect/hope a long and successful life :)